# where can I download financial statements (or financial data) for firms in many industries in one shot?

Tags: paneldata, corporate-finance, empirical-evidence, micro-data, data

I'm interested in doing some empirical analysis of firm's financial statements (such as asset, working capital, operating cost, etc) for many firms across industries over the past few years. Where can I download such dataset? (It would be great if I could download such dataset in one shot, instead of having to manually collect and combine dataset from different industries or years) Thanks!

Comment: capitaliq.com has these, but you have to pay, I am afraid.

Comment: @BrsG Thank you very much!